# Get nested JSON value with chained key in Java

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON object like the one below. Is it possible in Java to get a nested value from one get call using a chained key? For example:

```
String fname = jsonObj.get("shipmentlocation.personName.first")

{
    "shipmentLocation": {
        "personName": {
            "first": “firstName”,
            "generationalSuffix": "string",
            "last": "string",
            "middle": "string",
            "preferredFirst": "string",
            "prefix": "string",
            "professionalSuffixes": [
                "string"
            ]
        }
    },
    "trackingNumber": "string"
}
```

This did not work for me using the JSONObject class so I'm curious is there is an alternative method to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Guess that depends on which JSON library you're using, but likely not with normal JSON libraries. What you're looking for is a JSONPath library, e.g. https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#jayway-jsonpath

Comment: I think this will work. Thank you!

Comment: @Andreas , you should make your comment an answer. It is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

With the json you provided, you need to go through a few levels.

```
String firstName = jsonObj.getJSONObject("shipmentLocation").getJSONObject("personName").getString("first");
```

Be mindful that if any of the fields you're looking for in your json node or its subnodes may not be present, you can run into some null pointer problems with the above. In that case, it may be wiser to either have a look at java `Optional`s or just use null checking at each step like so:

```
String firstName = null;

JSONObject shipmentLocation = jsonObj.getJSONObject("shipmentLocation");
if (shipmentLocation != null) {
    JSONObject personName = shipmentLocation.getJSONObject("personName");
    if (personName != null) {
        firstName = personName.getString("first");
    }
}

if (firstName != null) {
    // do something with the first name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this library - json-simple-1.1.jar (link - http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonsimple11jar.htm)

```
String name = "";

JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader("Path to your file"));
JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonObject.get("shipmentLocation");
JSONObject jsonObject3 = jsonObject2.get("personName");
name = jsonObject3.get("first").toString();
```

Comment: `shipmentLocation` is not an array.